# WSDL service for plain XML instead of SOAP

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

Can I have a WSDL which will just use plain XML data and not SOAP?

If so could you please provide me a sample WSDL?

Comment: SOAP is the standard exchange format for WSDL, which is also valid XML. Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: Note that WSDL stands for Web Services Definition Language - so it's going to be hard to separate a WSDL from SOAP

Answer (score 21):

Yes, sending plain XML data over HTTP can be described in WSDL. Instead of using `<soap:binding>` when defining your operation's binding, you would instead use `<http:binding>`. For example:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:example" xmlns:tns="urn:example">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:example">
        <element name="content">
            <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="first" type="string"/>
                <element name="second" type="integer"/>
            </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        </schema>
    </types>

    <message name="id">
        <part name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>

    <message name="info">
        <part name="info" type="tns:content"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="widgetPortType">
        <operation name="getInfo">
        <input message="tns:id"/>
        <output message="tns:info"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="binding" type="tns:widgetPortType">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <operation name="getInfo">
        <http:operation location="getInfo"/>
        <input>
            <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <mime:mimeXml/>
        </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="widgetService">
        <port name="port" binding="tns:binding">
        <http:address location="http://www.example.org/"/>
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

You can find additional information about using an HTTP binding here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0830/cnfg_http-bc-get-processing_r/index.html

Comment: I'm sure this is right, but I always get `The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled`.  XML is so frustrating...

Comment: In Eclipse, I had to remove the <types> part of this wsdl sample in order to create a web service and a web service client. (Of course, also replace "tns:content" with another type, eg "xsd:string").